# Choice of chart induces an implicit one representative

Tags: differential-geometry

I chronically never get what was "abused" whenever an author says "abuse of notation". For this time, I am guessing, if the notation is "abused" because the embedding image $x(p)$ actually is the choice of chart induces an implicit one representative, but we still represent it as $(x^1(p), \ldots, x^n(p))$ without reflecting the fact that there has been an implicit choice?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand what's being abused in this example either. In general I think abuse of notation usually refers to overloading (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the text explains rather clearly what the "abuse of notation" is here.  Namely, it is an identification of $\mathcal U$ with $\mathcal U'$.  More specifically, the definite article in the phrase "the local coordinates" is a bit misleading, since, as you mentioned, all depends on a choice of a local chart.  Your hunch is correct!

Comment: That's so helpful! Thank you very much for assuring me!